# Could not load file or assembly MyNunitTest.dll or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper-10.0

I cannot run Nunit in the newest .NET. Here are all the steps I do:

1. New Project > Class Library (Package)
2. Add NUnit 3.0.1
3. Add the class:

Content:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace MyNunitTest
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestClass
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod()
        {
            Assert.That(true, Is.True);
        }
    }
}
```

4. Run All

Error:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly MyNunitTest.dll or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: Did you try update to resharper 10.02? I had big issues with nunit and resharper 10.01. They are gone since the update to 10.02.

Comment: @TomB. Yes, I have currently 10.0.2, I am at a loss :( Been fighting with this for like 3 hours, it doesn't work even with this simplest case - all the time `Inconclusive: Test not run`.

Comment: Helpfull for other people, maybe for you to. As a documentation reference: https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2015/11/09/resharper-10-critical-issues-and-fix-schedule/

Comment: Don't forget to log a ticket at resharper, they are helpfull

Comment: You say you did New Project > Class Library (Package) but you should at a New **Unit Test** Project instead. Please try this and add your testclass there. It will add more needed dependencies. Add you nuget in this project as well.

Comment: @TomB. It seems to be working with that type of class. But although it resolves the issue of *just running tests*, I cannot reference my ASP.NET 5 project anymore (different architecture I guess...

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue at all. Make sure the framework are the same (for example everything is .net framework 4.5). You can set this in project properties. Use both of these projects in one shared solution.

Comment: @TomB. Found a solution. Removed NUnit, Installed Xunit. Works :D

Comment: I posted the answer that applies to your main problem for future reference for other users. Can you mark that one as applicable for the described problem/exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the main problem here is that the wrong project type has been chosen.

To add a unit test project add a new **Unit test project** instead of a class library or any other type of project. Everything will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using Resharper 9.2, maybe you'll get your problem solved when you update.

Comment: Hmm... my version is 10.0.2, which is up-to-date... :/

Comment: Could you remove Resharper cache, and then try again ?

Comment: Unfortunately no effect. I do this in two ways - deleted cache files manually, didn't work. Used the Options > Environment > General > Clean caches. Didn't work :/ Restarted the computer, no effect either.

Comment: Weird, have you tried Unistall and then Install Resharper again ?

Comment: I think that won't be needed, see my comments on the initial post